# Images _display_name is changed in external db at com.android.provider.media/external.db

Tags: android

I am using  MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI(External DB :: data/data/com.android.provider.media/external.db)) in my app to save images with my own _display_name for example : image_101.jpg but after some time the display name is change into long no. like 1327392947034.jpg. and next time when i fetch the image with my _display_name(image_101.jpg) it found nothing in external db. can anyone tell me why it happens ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this happens when the `MediaScanner` adds the file to the internal `MediaStore.`  I think the numbers are related to `System.currentTimeMillis();` (salted hash, or similar).  I think this is to reduce the likely-hood of filename collision (two images with the same name).

There should be a way to separate display names from file names however.  When you say "my _display_name" are you referring to a column in the MediaStore you "added" (eg "data2") ?  Or are you using the `DISPLAY_NAME` (`android.provider.MediaStore.MediaColumns`) column?  You could also look at putting you custom name in the `DESCRIPTION` column.

One workaround would be to keep your own db of display names with a column for the ID in the Media store.

Also how are you inserting the image? Are you using an SQL query or one of the:

`insertImage(ContentResolver cr, String imgPath, String name, String desc)`

methods from `MediaStore.Images.Media` ?

A bit more code would help but maybe some of this answer can help.